# titleForHeaderSection from NSTableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, plist

How can I retrieve the current header section name from an `NSTableViewCell` item?

Currently I have a method called `configureCell` which determines how to style the custom cell I have. This data comes from a pList file.

```
-(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)tableViewCell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UILabel *label;
    UIView *backView;

    // NSString *country = [self tableView: tableViewCell titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
    NSString *fatPercent = [[self.milkTypes valueForKey:@"Finland"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    label = (UILabel *)[tableViewCell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = @"Fat Percent test";

    backView = (UIView *)[tableViewCell viewWithTag:2];

    backView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString: fatPercent];
}
```

Where I've commented out the line for `*country` I need to retrieve the current section I'm in. Currently it's statically set to `Finland` which is the array name from the pList.

For a better understanding on how my code is laid out, here is the majority of the Table Controller.

```
    - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
        return [self.milkTypes count];
    }

    - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            return [[self.milkTypes allKeys] objectAtIndex:section];
    }

    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
            NSString *country = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
            return [[self.milkTypes valueForKey:country] count];
    }

    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSString *cellIdentifier;
        UITableViewCell *cell;
        cellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MilkCell"];

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell = [self tableViewCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath]; 
        }
        [self configureCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;
    }


    -(UITableViewCell *)tableViewCellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        CGRect rect;
        UILabel *label;
        UIView *backView;
        UITableViewCell *cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];

        float center = (float) (40-20)/2;

        rect = CGRectMake(15, center, 270, 20);
        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:rect]; 
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        label.tag = 1;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
        [label release];

        rect = CGRectMake(280, 10, 20, 40-20);
        backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
        backView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        backView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        backView.tag = 2;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:backView];
        [backView release];

        return cell;
    }

    -(void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)tableViewCell forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        UILabel *label;
        UIView *backView;

    //      NSString *country = [self tableView: tableViewCell titleForHeaderInSection:indexPath.section];
            NSString *fatPercent = [[self.milkTypes valueForKey:@"Sweden"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        label = (UILabel *)[tableViewCell viewWithTag:1];
        label.text = @"Fat Percent test";

        backView = (UIView *)[tableViewCell viewWithTag:2];

            backView.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString: fatPercent];
    }
```

Comment: Do you not have an array of section headers anyway that you can select from using the indexPath.section value?

Comment: Stupidly no. I'm kind of new to iOS development and trying to get my head round some of the differences that I'm used to. Examples of storing sections in array?

Comment: Even if I had it in an array, how would I get the right section from it?

Comment: If your array of countries was NSArray *countries = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"Finland", @"Denmark", @"Sweden", nil] then you'd get the country name as NSString *country = [countries objectAtIndex: indexPath.section];

Comment: Can I generate that array for `countries` from the pList?

Comment: Not sure without seeing it :) Can you post that here too?

Comment: It seems you already have it anyway, in [[self.milkTypes allKeys] objectAtIndex:section] - just use that :)

Comment: I can't use `section` in `configureCell` though?

Comment: Sorry, `indexPath.section` sorted it! Cheers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you already have it anyway, in [[self.milkTypes allKeys] objectAtIndex:section] - just use that instead, so

```
NSString *country = [[self.milkTypes allKeys] objectAtIndex: indexPath.section];
```